# LCD problems: brightness / contrast blown out, can't bring up menu

Tags: graphics-card, colors, lcd, brightness

Yesterday, when I turned on my LCD monitor, the colors were very very bright. It looks as if someone had gone into the monitor on-screen-display and turned up brightness & contrast all the way to the max. Colors were washed out, and it's almost painful to look at. So I tried to go into the menu and see if the settings were wrong somehow...and I found that I cannot bring up the menu. All the buttons on the front of the monitor now do nothing, except the power button.

I was able to go into my graphics card settings, and turn the brightness way down to compensate, so it's at least usable for now, but it's not quite right, there is definitely some loss of color resolution or something from the two extreme settings canceling each other out.

Any ideas what kind of failure in the LCD might cause this?

According to the control panel, the model number is: KL2490DW-D

It's a 24" 1920x1200 with the brand "synaps".

Comment: Can't pinpoint a specific cause, but some googling about your question suggests that Synaps monitors are very poorly made.  Dead pixels, random failures after short periods of time, etc seem to be mentioned in half the reviews I've come across.  I'd say try to return it--there's likely nothing you can do on your end.

Answer (score 1):

If the buttons on the monitor do not work, then the monitor is dying.

It could have been a power glitch, or just a bad monitor to start with.

If the monitor is still under warranty, then use it.
Otherwise, get a new monitor (not Synaps).

If your computer is not protected by an anti-surge, then get some protection such as a surge outlet or a UPS, before changing the monitor.

Comment: The LCD panel itself is fine, my guess is the controller chip is somehow failing. I've had it for 13 months, and it looks like there is a 3 year warranty, so I'll probably just go that way versus opening it and looking for blown capacitors or something.

Comment: @davr: Careful - opening it up may void the warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try unplugging the monitor, both power & video, and then reconnecting? Did you try another video cable?

Also, you may want to check the gamma setting if it's available through the display properties.